# text classification - does number of features matters?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, scikit-learn, text-classification

I'm working on a multi-class text classification project that aims to assign a "new bug" to his "final group assignee"

To do that I was able to extract ~17000 samples and divided each sample to the below (all text features):

1. Subject
2. Description
3. Comments
4. Has images (boolean field) ==> ('yes' or 'no')
5. Involved groups
6. Committer groups
7. Reporter group
8. Assignee group
9. Group name <== this is the label (the final class I want to predict)

I've 6 classes (labels) overall

**My main question:**

Since all of my data is text, I'm kinda wondering: does the neural network expects all features (columns) to be gathered to a single one?
(Since all of them will be feed via some kind of tokenizer anyway)

I've tried 2 approaches/libraries (`sklearn` and `keras`):

When using sklearn, I kept the columns and processed each one with `TfidfVectorizer`, but when I tried to explore keras, I couldn't (or didn't understand how to) do it.

Also - for keras, all of the examples I've seen so far took 1 columns and processed it.

I've very confused with how I should continue from this point on.
I'll just mention, that using sklearn I was able to get ~70% score vs keras (after uniting all columns) where I got ~60%

Comment: A text field like "description" is not a single feature, it needs to be encoded. Categorical variables like "assignee group" can be either encoded together with the text (but then you lose the specific semantics of the feature) or concatenated to the text features after encoding. It's a design choice. Also I don't know what you use as "score" but if it's accuracy it's problably not good enough for a multiclass problem.

Comment: @Erwan what I meant is that I'm using 9 different features - not 1 - I don't want to unit them to a single one. so I've 9 inputs (all text) and 1 output (which can be either 1 of 6 possible labels/classes).

Comment: yes I understand. Each of these 9 input features needs to be encoded into a vector of features, either a traditional bag of words encoding like TfidfVectorizer or some form of embedding. If you want to keep the 9 original features distinct, you'll obtain 9 sets of features which can be concatenated together. But a high number of dimensions can cause problems too, that depends on the data.

Comment: @Erwan can you suggest how should I approach it? I've learned by now that `keras` Sequential model is a no go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372433/neural-network-with-several-inputs-keras-text-classification as it only serves the purpose of 1 dimension feature, so my question is: what is the correct way?

Comment: I'm not an expert in DL so I'll let somebody more knowledgeable answer this part. With traditional ML this is what I explained above: if you want to keep the original features separated, you should encode each of them independently then put all the resulting features together. For example you might obtain 700 features for subject, 2000 features for description, etc., at the end you have 700+2000+... features in total. But this approach risks producing too many features, that's why people often choose to concatenate all the text features together first.

Comment: @Erwan by 700 + 2000 features, is it possible you mean dimensions? I'm a bit confused by the terminology but I was under the impression that each dataset column == feature

Comment: yes I mean "dimensions", but these "dimensions" are actually the "features" for the model. Technically speaking, the number of "original features", i.e. the number of columns in the original dataset, is irrelevant. For example your features 7 and 8 could be represented as a single column containing the two values concatenated; it wouldn't be semantically meaningful but it would contain exactly the same information. Conversely there could be a column which could be split into several columns. In other words the number and meaning of the features is a matter of design, so the important ...

Comment: ... question is how the information fed to the model is represented.